# XML parsing from file to text PYTHON

Tags: python, xml

I need to get text values from XML files in Python.

My actual XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
        <command>first</command>
        <command>second</command>
        <command>third</command>
</data>
```

I need read it from a file and then obtain an output like:

```
first
second
third
```

Im doing a little source like:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.parse("C:\ciao.xml")
name = doc.getElementsByTagName("command")[0]
print(name.firstChild.data)
```

But i need get all commands and not just one by one

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop?

```
for name in doc.getElementsByTagName("command"):
    print(name.firstChild.data)
```

If you need to store those in a list use a list comprehension,

```
data = [i.firstChild.data for i in doc.getElementsByTagName("command")]
```

Comment: Oh finally someone who helped me. love you

Comment: just a little, hope little, more question:
Now i have all values, but i need also put them into a var in format:
first;second;third;
How can i do this? :P

Answer (score 0):

You could use BeautifulSoup.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> xml = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
        <command>first</command>
        <command>second</command>
        <command>third</command>
</data>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
>>> for i in soup.find_all('command'):
    print(i.text)


first
second
third
```